# quick integration notation question

Tags: notation, definite-integrals, contour-integration

What exactly does the base of this integral sign refer to?
$$\int\limits_{[0\to 1]}$$
Is that an arbitrary contour from the point $0$ to the point $1$? (this is complex analysis)

ps. Here's the context and motivation, as requested.
[image]

Comment: Where are you seeing this notation? Textbook, journal article, teacher's own notation... ?

Comment: It's an exam question, and I'm being asked to show that a series converges uniformly and then use that fact to show that integrating (with the above symbol) its limit function results in a  given series. The integrand is a series (summation) of rational functions of z.

Comment: Some context would be very helpful here.  What is the rest of the expression?

Comment: Looks like a typo to me, though if it was something like "with $t \rightarrow 0 $", the square brackets should not be there...

Comment: @Igor It's not a typo because the notation gets used every year. I don't know where the exam-setter got the notation from.

Comment: Yep, I understand... But could you please add the rest of the formula (and, possibly, the textual part of the problem too)?

Comment: I would guess that your interpretation is correct, but as already stated some context would be nice.

Comment: I think it just means the regular real integral $\int_0^1$, and the arrow indicates you progress forward over the real interval $[0,1]$ with positive $dx$, rather than backwards.

Comment: It would be strange if an arbitrary contour were allowed, when you are asked to work within $D(0,2)$.

Comment: @alex.jordan an arbitrary contour within D, I mean, so that the fundamental thm of calculus may be applied.